# Call C++ from Java with multiple arguments and three functions

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I have a previously written C++ code which I want to put a Java user interface on it. This C++ code executes three different algorithms that require some user defined data types as input and pass their outputs in the same user defined arguments.
I need a sample code written in JNA (Java Native Access) which have two characteristics: first, calls several functions in one dll with different names and second, pass arguments for both input and output.
Can someone help me?

Comment: That's actually pretty easy. Too bad you don't have any means to set a bounty to make it worth while. Have you given the reference a look? It's pretty straight forward. Also, I believe you might be talking about *JNI* (Java Native *Interface*).

Comment: I spend so much time on JNI to call these functions but it was really problematic and couldn't make it done. Do you have any examples which I can use?

Comment: Not a good idea to ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: The examples I have are from Java: The Complete Reference which I would have to retype. Not only that, but it requires more of an explanation than what is on the surface. You have to compile it with certain options etc... I would suggest not going this route. It makes Java +/- pointless for it looses portability and security risky for it's possible to wrap C/C++ that uses inline ASM!!, among others. Try searching google/Oracle. Also, the syntax is so close it should be criminal. I just re-implemented large amounts of C++ code to J by copy/paste/check 4 diffs. It's really that easy!-IMHO!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instructional example to help get you started.  In this snippet, Java2Win64 is the DLL that contains the native code to execute. Function functionMaryam() takes 1 param as int and returns an int.  Easy to expand for any data type.

```
public class JnaExampleMaryam {

// ------------------------------------------
// Java2Win.class
// ------------------------------------------
public interface Java2Win extends Library {
    Java2Win call = (Java2Win) Native.loadLibrary("Java2Win64", Java2Win.class);

    int functionMaryam(int i);
}

// ------------------------------------------

// ------------------------------------------
// Test
// ------------------------------------------
public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
    final File file = new File("rootToDLL", "Java2Win64.dll");
    LibraryLoader.loadLibrary(file);

    int result = Java2Win.call.functionMaryam(42);

}
// ------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: My function is defined like this:
'extern "C" void PASCAL EXPORT RCS( stAct* act,stResourceDirectory* resDir,   stCalendar* calendar, short  numOfAct, short numOfRes, short numOfCal, int nDataDate );'
Do you think it will work to call it this way:
'RCS(stAct* act, stResourceDirectory* redDir, ... );'

Comment: @Maryam - Create a new question titled "How do I define a JNA library interface for methods using Pascal calling convention?